# Creating JSON with iOS 5 - issues

Tags: ios, json

I'm trying to create a JSON object that looks like this:

```
  { "request_type":"send_string" "security_level":0 "device_type":"ios" "blob":{"string":"blah"}"}
```

Here's my attempt:

```
NSDictionary *blobData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          sendString,@"string",
                          nil];
NSString *blobString = [[NSString alloc]
                        initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:blobData options:kNilOptions error:&error]
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Blob Created: %@", blobString);
NSDictionary *requestData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"send_string",@"request_type",
                             0,@"security_level",
                             @"ios",@"device_type",
                             //No Email Provided, This is just for testing
                             blobString,@"blob",
                             nil];

NSData *JSONRequestData = NULL;
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:requestData]) {
    NSLog(@"Proper JSON Object");
    JSONRequestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"requestData was not a proper JSON object");
    return FALSE;
}
NSLog(@"%@",[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSDebugDescription"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONRequestData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

The problem is, that last NSLog tells me all I've created is something like this:

```
{"request_type":"send_string"}
```

So when I go and try to write this to the server with

```
[NSJSONSerialization writeJSONObject:JSONRequestData toStream:outputStream options:0 error:&error];
```

I get this error from the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization writeJSONObject:toStream:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line

```
0,@"security_level"
```

with

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"security_level"
```

Comment: Awesome, I completely forgot that a NSDictionary must consist of objects. The integer must be placed in an NSNumber object.
I'm still having trouble with the last line. I still get the "Invalid top-level type in JSON write" error